# Issue in on top side menu command

Tags: codenameone

The text in side menu command exceeds the width of the side menu, which makes somewhat peculiar effect.

see the video [here](https://youtu.be/SCDYmmiodcE)

How can I set multiline as in textArea in this case?

```
 Command protectedPlantAndSpecies = new Command("  Protected plants and species of nepal", protectedPlantIcon) {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            new Notification(res).show();
        }
    };
    f.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu(protectedPlantAndSpecies);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tickering which is enabled by default, you can disable it by calling this in your `init(Object)` method:

```
Label.setDefaultTickerEnabled(false);
```

You can also set the theme constant `tickerSpeedInt` to 0.

Comment: If the command exceeds the width of side menu, it'll be nice to have the excess word in 2nd line though as in textArea where we can set growLimit.

Comment: You can use `addComponentToSideMenu` with a `SpanButton` or similar